# Is it safe to memcpy struct with arrays and some methods?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am wondering if it is safe to use memcpy on a struct that contain arrays and methods(just some getters and setters since indexing of arrays is unusual and i have to map it somehow). I know that its is safe for PODs and I am unsure if my struct would be considered POD or not?

Comment: *Non-virtual* member functions, yes. See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#pod-types.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `memcpy` if the `struct` is [TriviallyCopyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable).

You can check whether your `struct` is trivially copyable by using [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable).

Also, as pointed out by @JohanLundberg in a comment, the destination address must be `0` modulo `std::alignment_of<T>`. You can read more about alignment requirements of objects at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment.

Comment: Funnily enough, that includes e.g. `std::atomic<T>` or types with explicitly deleted copy semantics.

Comment: What about alignment concerns? Don't you also need to make sure the destination is 0 modulo std::alignment_of<T> ?